# return a value from javascript function and then execute code inside it

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, browser, settimeout, setinterval

I have a javascript function which needs to return true in order to update the browser UI. How can I make sure the function returns before executing the code to make a backend call?

```
 self.resortCopy = function(item) {
 self.resorts.push(item);
 self.backendCall(item) // this needs to be performed after returning true
 return true;
```

Comment: There's really no way to place the function call after the return statement, the best you can hope for is deferring the execution with a timeout, and hope that works.

Comment: Is this browser JS or NodeJS? If browser, how far back does it need to support? If NodeJS, which version? Makes a difference as to what language features are available.

Comment: It is already async. When you call `self.backendCall(item)` js does not wait for it to finish and calls next line `return true` immediately.

Comment: @OleksiiChekulaiev okay thanks. I guess something else is an issue then

Comment: @OleksiiChekulaiev, that's not correct. Whatever code is in backendCall will execute first. If that code includes an XHR or worker execution or some other async task, its callback will not be waited on, but all the other code will run synchronously.

Comment: @hemp agree. I supposed that backendCall does involve AJAX looking at it's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you are having a ajax request inside self.backendCall (XHR/fetch)

If that is true, then your code already async

Else, look at @hemp's answer

```js
function ajax(){
  fetch("https://httpbin.org/get").then(data=>{
    console.log("DONE")
  })
}

function test(){
  ajax();
  return true;
}

console.log(test())
```

Comment: Word of warning, the fetch API is not supported in any version of IE.

Comment: @hemp Nighter are the arrow function, but the XHR are such a mess to write out for the sake of this demo.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming browser JS, you can use setTimeout universally, this will guarantee that the current codepath finishes before the backendCall code executes, but it doesn't say anything else about when (unless you specify a timeout period.)

```
self.resortCopy = function(item) {
self.resorts.push(item);
window.setTimeout(self.backendCall.bind(self, item), 0);
return true;
```

Comment: It is regular Js. Didn't know could do that way, but as per comments, the code is already asyc

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with "regular JS" as a specifier. Even if it's in a browser, which browsers are being targeted makes a huge difference.

Comment: sorry I meant, javascript from browser (chrome) doing an ajax to call backend service. Not using any frameworks here.